# How can I print the activations of each layer of a model while training the same Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The following code (based on https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) allows us to print the output of an intermediate layer of a model, *given some input*, which we need to provide. Specifically, in this example, I am printing the output of the layer `dense`, given the input to the layer `input_1`, which also happens to be the input layer of my model (but this does not have to be like that).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def get_model():
    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(inp)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    return model


def train():
    my_model = get_model()
    my_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

    get_layer_output = tf.keras.backend.function([my_model.get_layer("input_1").input],
                                                 [my_model.get_layer("dense").output])

    data_x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
    layer_output = get_layer_output(data_x)[0]
    print(layer_output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

However, I would like to print the output of each layer, given the output of the corresponding previous layer (as defined by the model), while training the model, i.e. after each mini-batch. I tried to use a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/), which calls `tf.print` for printing the output of a model, but I am getting an error, which is described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35949) (i.e. there is a bug in TensorFlow 2.0, which is the version I am using and that I want to use).

To be clearer, I would like to debug the output of each layer while I am training the model, so that I can understand how the inputs flow throughout each layer and if the activations are not too high (explode) or too small (vanish). I could iteratively provide a batch of data to `get_layer_output`, but I would like to be able to print the activations of each layer while training the model with `fit` or `fit_generator`. Furthermore, I would like to understand how the values of the activations evolve from the input layer to the output layer and not just print the activations of one layer given the input to another layer.

Here's [a Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3469) that asks a similar thing.